# Does $\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

For random variables X and Y, does $\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)$? I know that the expectation of $X+Y$ is $\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}(Y)$, so does it work for squares, too?

Comment: This is just the same formula!

Comment: Yes. Just to add to the above: we can see this more clearly by defining $A = X^2$ and $B = Y^2$ and applying the identity to $\mathbb{E}(A+B)$.

Comment: Just a trick. The expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ has similar properties to the integral operator $\int$ (this is easy to see, since the expectation is basically an integral), and taking into account that $\int f^2 +g^2 = \int f^2 +\int g^2$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, it works for squares too.

But it is important to see why this follows directly from $\mathbb{E}(X + Y) = \mathbb{E}(X) + \mathbb{E}(Y)$. This equality holds for *any* random variables, and since $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are random variables in their own right, it also holds for them.

If you want, we can set $U=X^2$ and $V=Y^2$. Then since $U$ and $V$ are random variables, we have $\mathbb{E}(U+V) = \mathbb{E}(U) + \mathbb{E}(V)$, or, by substituting the $X^2$ and $Y^2$ back in, that
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) + \mathbb{E}(Y^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

In identities such as $\mathrm{E}(X+Y)=\mathrm{E}(X)+\mathrm{E}(Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ are both simply placeholders for any two random variables. $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are also random variables, meaning that the identity still applies. It's for the same reason that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ implies $\sin^2(x^2)+\cos^2(x^2)=1$.